# echo command issue on Unix server

Tags: unix, echo

I am trying to copy some configurations to unix endpoint using below echo command, after copying i see few characters are missing or sometimes gets prefixes.  example below.

need your suggestion here.

```
set system login user b48368 authentication encrypted-password '$1$trz5zI9f$2jL1PHnXNxY/'
set system login user b48368 authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user bb0k93 authentication encrypted-password '$1$/y8uENjM$C7WQQZDQRbRJOeh/'
set system login user bb0k93 authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user bb0k93 level 'admin'
set system login user bb0r4w authentication encrypted-password '$1$2.i88iIa$ZkREPOKUNjaJflNJ4/'
set system login user bb0r4w authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user 430140 authentication encrypted-password '$1$qs.a5lXh$zjsssrtmCjsaSIfAv1'
set system login user 430140 authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user 430140 level 'admin'
set system login user pa3n authentication encrypted-password '$1$yffNZqPG$EpMR/2RxniVYq0'
set system login user pat3n authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user pa4n authentication encrypted-password '$1$NKWjQnX8$ZExZcYAm7ECEyI2/'
set system login user pa4n authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user pa5n authentication encrypted-password '$1$8Km21dzm$q2NlHcRlZX1Oc6M0'
set system login user pa5n authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user pa6n authentication encrypted-password '$1$qjkBDXXU$vJn4o6gF7aK/i/'
set system login user patn authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user root authentication encrypted-password '$1$T1PHVDEj$UXtfPX/yuGtm0'
set system login user root authentication plaintext-password ''
```

Copied output, missing few characters

```
set system login user a48368 authentication encrypted-password 'jL1hU238TJXNxY/'
set system login user a48368 authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user ab0k93 authentication encrypted-password '$/y8uENjM/'
set system login user ab0k93 authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user ab0k93 level 'admin'
set system login user ab0r4w authentication encrypted-password '.i88iIa/'
set system login user ab0r4w authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user 430140 authentication encrypted-password '.a5lXh'
set system login user 430140 authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user 430140 level 'admin'
set system login user pt3n authentication encrypted-password '/2RxnpQU7CiVYq0'
set system login user pa3n authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user pa4n authentication encrypted-password '/'
set system login user pa4n authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user pa5n authentication encrypted-password 'Km21dzm'
set system login user pa5n authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user pa6n authentication encrypted-password '/oAi/'
set system login user pa6n authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user root authentication encrypted-password '/yuGtuKm0'
```

Comment: Why wasa this downvoted?

Comment: You might want to change the passwords of the associated users, as the encrypted versions you have posted can be brute-forced or looked up.

Answer (score 3):

When you have used the echo command you have most likely enquoted it in double quotes.   This allows for some interpretation of the text - notably $XXX is recognised as the variable XXX and references to it will be replaced with the contents of that variable (normally nothing).

In order to get arround this you need to enter the data differently or properly escape the strings - you can most likely do this in your case by prefixing the "$" symbol with a "\" to ensure it gets interpreted literally.

You have not advised how you are using this (eg the source), but a another way to handle it might be to use "[Here Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash#2500451)", which allows you to treat input from a source file as raw text and redirect it